# configuring website using windows server2003,IIS6.0 and MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-6, webserver

I have been going through http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx but so far I have not been able to configure my website.  These are the steps I have done:

1. Downloaded and installed .net 4.0
2. I have built and published my website to inetpub/root on windows server2003
3. I have used IIS to do the cofiguration as per haacked.  It seems that despite setting the asp.net 4.0(please see image) in the webservice extensions

Answer (score 0):

You should change the path to aspnet_isapi.dll to the one from .NET 4:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_isapi.dll`

Answer (score 0):

did you install MVC on the server? So that it has the MVC DLLs

[MVC install](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)